# Swing worker unable to update Jprogressbar during import

Tags: java, swingworker, jprogressbar

Hi am still a learner when it comes to SwingWorker implementation. Im currently developing a Desktop App with swing that upload a very large amount of data which takes about 15 secs. i wanted to use swingworker to manage the task and update a jPrgressBar of which am failing.
below is the code am using

```
private class Update extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        importData();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
                return null;
    }
    protected void done(){

    }
}
```

this private class has the import method and i understand i have to implement a propertyychagelistner to the jprogressbar to monitor and update my progress bar and the code am using is below.

```
public void runProgress(){
Update task = new Update();
task.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener(){
@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())){
        jProgressBar1.setIndeterminate(false);
        jProgressBar1.setValue((Integer) evt.getNewValue());
    }
}
});
    task.execute();
 }
```

I then call the runPregress method under the jButton actionedperformed. the data is being imported successfully but nothing is happening to the progress bar. Please help me solve my problem and try to give as much explanation as possible as am still learning how swingworker works

Answer (score 0):

Look at the last example in the documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Call the method "setProgress()" in your method "doInBackGround()". You should call it several times like in the very last example (PrimeNumbersTask).